# What is the number that follows in this sequence?

Tags: logical-deduction, number-sequence

> $4, 2, 3, 6, 4, 7, 2, 4, ?$

Hopefully this wasn't posted already. It's not hard, let's see how quickly you get this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> 8

Because:

> The number of letters in "sequence". The previous numbers come from the the number of letters in the words of the title in order.

Comment: Correct! I told you it was easy.